# How to check the version of OpenMP on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, version, openmp

I wonder how to check the version of OpenMP on a Linux remote machine?

I don't know where it is installed either.

Comment: OpenMP is built-in into your compiler. I guess you should check the version of your compiler and refer to the manual to check OpenMP version.

Comment: If you want to check OpenMP version with clang, can use `echo | clang -fopenmp -dM -E - | grep -i openmp`.

Answer (score 73):

It appears that the C/C++ specification for OpenMP provides no direct way of doing this programmatically.  So you have to check the docs for your compiler version.

```
gcc --version ## get compiler version
```

For GCC, this is a good resource (does not mention newest versions of GCC): http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp:

> As of GCC 4.2, the compiler implements version 2.5 of the OpenMP standard and as of 4.4 it implements version 3.0 of the OpenMP standard. The OpenMP 3.1 is supported since GCC 4.7.

---

#### Edit

After trying a bit harder, I got the following to work. It at least gives an indication of the OpenMP version -- although it still requires you to look something up.

```
$ echo |cpp -fopenmp -dM |grep -i open
#define _OPENMP 200805
```

You can go here (http://www.openmp.org/specifications/) to discover the mapping between the date provided and the actual OpenMP version number.

> In implementations that support a preprocessor, the _OPENMP macro name is defined to have the decimal value yyyymm where yyyy and mm are the year and month designations of the version of the OpenMP API that the implementation supports.

Comment: Funny story: I spent a while trying to figure out how to find the OpenMP version programmatically before giving up and posting this answer. Then I noticed that it is irrelevant for my purposes because the specific feature that I wanted (taskyield) is not actually supported in any version of gcc (as indicated in the wiki referenced above).

Comment: For quick reference (copied from http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/), the mapping of `#define _OPENMP` to the OPENMP API version is `{200505:'2.5',200805:'3.0',201107:'3.1',201307:'4.0'}` where each pair is 'value of _OPENMP : OpenMP API Version'.

Comment: One more version for `_OPENMP` is {201511: '4.5'}.

Comment: *"It appears that the C/C++ specification for OpenMP provides no direct way of doing this programmatically...."* - Incorrect. The value is set in the macro `_OPENMP`.

Comment: @jww: I covered that in the edited answer.  My interpretation was that this returns a reference date, which is an indirect representation of the version, and not the version itself.  You still have to apply a translation if you want to get the commonly used version number.

Comment: There's an automated mapping for CMake at [Kitware/CMake/master/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.16.3/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake#L384), which may be related to [FineOpenMP](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindOpenMP.html).

Answer (score 29):

Here's a short C++11 program to display your OpenMP version; it also covers version 5.2 which was released in November 2021.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::unordered_map<unsigned,std::string> map{
    {199810,"1.0"},
    {200203,"2.0"},
    {200505,"2.5"},
    {200805,"3.0"},
    {201107,"3.1"},
    {201307,"4.0"},
    {201511,"4.5"},
    {201811,"5.0"},
    {202011,"5.1"},
    {202111,"5.2"}
  };
  std::cout << "We have OpenMP " << map.at(_OPENMP) << ".\n";
  return 0;
}
```

and compile it with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp foobar.cpp
```

Comment: for ICL 16.0.3 which claims 4.5 support it still reports 4.0

Comment: For VS2015.2 it produces no output.  It's mostly OpenMP 2.5 but doesn't define _OPENMP.

Comment: g++ 7.0 reports 4.5, 5.3 reports 4.0.

Comment: Add `{201811,"5.0"}` - see https://github.com/jeffhammond/HPCInfo/blob/master/docs/Preprocessor-Macros.md

Comment: {200203, "2.0"} for Visual Studio 2019 (yes, really)

Answer (score 10):

You need to check your `gcc` version using

```
gcc --version
```

and then see the (incomplete) table below (whose info is gathered from [this Wiki article](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) and from [this webpage](https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/) from the OpenMP official website):

```
| gcc version | OpenMP version |    Languages    | Offloading |
|-------------|----------------|-----------------|------------|
|    4.2.0    |       2.5      |        C        |            |
|    4.4.0    |       3.0      |        C        |            |
|    4.7.0    |       3.1      |        C        |            |
|    4.9.0    |       4.0      |      C, C++     |            |
|    4.9.1    |       4.0      | C, C++, Fortran |            |
|      5      |                |                 |     Yes    |
|     6.1     |       4.5      |      C, C++     |            |
```

The blank entries are there because I didn't find the corresponding info.

Answer (score 9):

First set environment variable [OMP_DISPLAY_ENV](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-TR6.pdf):
in bash:

```
export  OMP_DISPLAY_ENV="TRUE"
```

or in csh-like shell:

```
setenv OMP_DISPLAY_ENV TRUE
```

Then compile and run your OpenMP program:

```
./a.out
```

There will be additional info, like :

```
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
  _OPENMP = '201511'
  OMP_DYNAMIC = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NESTED = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NUM_THREADS = '8'
  OMP_SCHEDULE = 'DYNAMIC'
  OMP_PROC_BIND = 'FALSE'
  OMP_PLACES = ''
  OMP_STACKSIZE = '0'
  OMP_WAIT_POLICY = 'PASSIVE'
  OMP_THREAD_LIMIT = '4294967295'
  OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS = '2147483647'
  OMP_CANCELLATION = 'FALSE'
  OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE = '0'
  OMP_MAX_TASK_PRIORITY = '0'
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END
```

where _OPENMP have the
8 decimal value yyyymm where yyyy and mm are the year and month designations of the version of the OpenMP API that the implementation supports.

Comment: by far the simplest answer here!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think you can not get the version of openmp directly, but compiler will use a predefined macro `_OPENMP` to represent the release date of openmp, and you should specify the `-fopenmp` option to use this macro.

You can get the release date of openmp first using shell command like this

```
echo _OPENMP | gcc -fopenmp -E -x c - | tail -1
```

As for my gcc, it is

```
201511
```

Then you can check the openmp release history (https://www.openmp.org/news/press-releases/) to get the version. Of `201511`, it means Nov 2015, and the version is `openmp 4.5` .

The release history is below:

```
Date        Version
----------------------
Nov 2021    OpenMP 5.2
Nov 2020    OpenMP 5.1
Nov 2018    OpenMP 5.0
Nov 2015    OpenMP 4.5
Jul 2013    OpenMP 4.0
Jul 2011    OpenMP 3.1
May 2008    OpenMP 3.0
May 2005    OpenMP 2.5
Mar 2002    C/C++ 2.0
Nov 2000    Fortran 2.0
Nov 1999    Fortran 1.1
Oct 1998    C/C++ 1.0
Oct 1997    Fortran 1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenMP documentation improved a lot. You can find more information about supported OpenMP versions corresponding compilers from [this](https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/) link.

Coming to your question, as mentioned above first find the gcc compiler version and then refer the above link to know the corresponding OpenMP version.

Above link also has the supported OpenMP versions in the different compliers.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it by running a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
  #ifdef _OPENMP
    printf("OpenMP version: %d\n", _OPENMP);
  #else
    printf("No OpenMP support\n");
  #endif
  return 0;
}
```

And then compile it with `GCC` or, as in my case, with `mpicc` by adding the flag `-fopenmp`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit safer version of an answer by [user2023370](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023370/user2023370) above. Ancient OpenMP versions are omitted for brevity:

```
#include <map>
#include <fmt/format.h>
using namespace std;
...
fmt::print("OpenMP v{}\n", map<int, string>{{200805, "3.0"},{201107, "3.1"}, {201307, "4.0"}, {201511, "4.5"}, {201811, "5.0"}}[_OPENMP]);
```

If a new version number or corrupted one is encountered, this statement will not throw exception as opposed to using `at()` function member.

Version numbers are from https://github.com/jeffhammond/HPCInfo/blob/master/docs/Preprocessor-Macros.md.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting OpenMP from the GNU Compiler Collection, a link provided by a commenter above was helpful: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp.

However, note that it states in this that while GCC 12 and 13 have (at least) feature completion up to 5.1 (and I think 5.2 for GCC 13), they nonetheless return the `_OPENMP` preprocessor value `201511` which corresponds to OpenMP 4.5.

In other words, if you're using one of the methods listed by another commenter to get the version from that `_OPENMP` value, it might be incorrect if you're getting OpenMP from GCC, and you might actually have features from 5.0+.