# OpenMP parallel for region thread affinity

Tags: c, openmp

Let's say I have the following OpenMP region:

```
omp_set_num_threads(3);
#pragma omp parallel for
{
 //start
 ...
 //somewhere in the middle
 ...
 //end
}
```

Let's say I have 8-core system. For example, after "start" let's say thread 0 is running on core 4, thread 1 runs on core 5, and thread 2 runs on core 6. Is it possible "somewhere in the middle" before the "end" that threads migrate from their respective cores that they were assigned after "start"? I.e. is it possible that threads 0-2 are assigned to cores 4-5 after "start", and "somewhere in the middle" threads say migrate to cores 5-7, respectively? And will even be possible that threads may reside just before the "end" on cores 0-2? Thanks.

Comment: It is not apparent from your question if you are asking for some sort of dynamic run-time control over the placement of threads or if your are just asking if it is possible in principle for threads to migrate to different cores while the parallel region executes.

Comment: @HristoIliev Second part, I was asking if it is possible in principle that threads migrate to different cores while the parallel region executes without explicitly asking to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @torem Remember: with privileges come responsibilities. Maybe you want to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on comments (especially the part _When shouldn't I comment?_)

Comment: @Massimiliano Sorry, if I did anything wrong. I just wanted to know the exact situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, OpenMP 3.1 specifications do not provide any means to re-bind threads.

In fact, the only way to have some control over thread binding is through the `OMP_PROC_BIND` environment variable:

> The **OMP_PROC_BIND** environment variable sets the value of the global bind-var ICV. The value of this environment variable must be **true** or **false**. If the environment variable is set to **true**, the execution environment should not move OpenMP threads between processors. If the environment variable is set to **false**, the execution environment may move OpenMP threads between processors. The behavior of the program is implementation defined if the value of **OMP_PROC_BIND** is neither **true** nor **false**.

The OpenMP 4.0 draft extends the possible values of `OMP_PROC_BIND` and adds the `OMP_PLACES` environment variable, which permits to select how threads are bound to resources. Still, there is no standard way of re-binding the threads.

If this behavior is for you absolutely necessary, you may think of using the [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) library, in particular the [CPU binding](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.6.1/a00053.php) part.

Comment: So, in the last part it says that exec env may move OpenMP threads between processors (when OMP_PROC_BIND=false). How do I know what my implementation defines in case of OMP_PROC_BIND is neither true nor false? Thanks.

Comment: @torem, you should take a look at the documentation of your compiler in order understand what the default OpenMP behaviour is. For example, both GCC/libgomp and Intel OpenMP do not bind threads when `OMP_PROC_BIND` has no value set.

Comment: @HristoIliev I looked at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc.pdf, also at gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp.pdf but nothing about OMP_PROC_BIND. Please could you give me a link? For example, my system gcc/gfortran --version shows 4.7.2. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @torem, the documentation of `OMP_PROC_BIND` in `libgomp` points to the GCC-specific [GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html#GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY): "If this environment variable is omitted, the host system will handle the assignment of threads to CPUs."

Comment: @HristoIliev In the second document there is no OMP_PROC_BIND, but there is GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY. It says that if this is not specified, i.e. neither true or false, the host system will handle the assignment of threads to CPUs. But it does not say whether it bind or not? Also, for example now I am using currently only "-fopenmp" falg, if I set GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY will I have to use the "-lgomp" flag too? Thanks a lot in advance! If you want I can ask these as a question, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: @torem, `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is a GNU extension to the OpenMP specification (the same way that Intel OpenMP supports the `KMP_AFFINTY`). Setting `OMP_PROC_BIND` enables thread binding while `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` specifies how exactly the binding should be performed. You only need to compile and link with `-fopenmp` and all the necessary libraries would be automatically linked.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks a lot! So, you mean that even if I specify GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY. Threads may be migrated between the set of cores that I specify in GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY if OMP_PROC_BIND is not set? Also where can I find what you have said regarding the OMP_PROC_BIND. Because while reading the OpenMP 3.1 spec, it says that "The behavior of the program is implementation defined if the value of OMP_PROC_BIND is neither true nor false." It does not say as you said "OpenMP do not bind threads when OMP_PROC_BIND has no value set.". Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @HristoIliev And finally how do I know which OpenMP Spec. exactly my system is using currently? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @HristoIliev This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304363/how-to-check-the-version-of-openmp-on-linux) suggests to run the "echo |cpp -fopenmp -dM |grep -i open", it shows "#define _OPENMP 201107". Is there anything like "gcc --version" command, that would show exactly the version of OpenMP my gnu is using currently? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It is badly documented but you can browse the source. If `OMP_PROC_BIND` is set to `true` and `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is not set, then threads are bound in a linear way: thread 0 to CPU 0, thread 1 to CPU 1, etc. If `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is also set, it gives the specific thread to core mapping. If `OMP_PROC_BIND` is not set or is set to `false` and `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is not set, then the affinity mechanism is not initialised. If `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is set, then thread binding is activated, no matter if `OMP_PROC_BIND` is set or not.

Comment: @torem, `201107` is July 2011, which corresponds to OpenMP version 3.1.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks a lot!!! Could you give me a link to source? I really appreciate your help! Thanks!!!

Comment: @HristoIliev So, there is no way I can ask my system something like OpenMP --version and it would give me 3.1? Thanks!!!

Comment: @torem, the source of `libgomp` in GCC 4.7.2 is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/tags/gcc_4_7_2_release/libgomp/). Yes, there is no way to obtain the OpenMP version in `x.y` format besides looking up the `yyyymm` number in a table.

Comment: @torem, also note that OpenMP support is part of the compiler. Generally the supported OpenMP version is determined at compile time by the compiler used. You can have many compilers installed and each one might support different OpenMP versions. Take a look at the [OpenMP page](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) in the GCC Wiki for a way to directly translate the GCC version into the supported OpenMP version (it's just one sentence really).

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks! I saw it from the stackoverflow question link that I have shown above, but I would really be happy to have it directly (with smth like "--version") from my system. THANKS A LOT!!!