# Unable to install dependencies for docker image using conda

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, conda

I am trying to dockerize a flask backend which has the dependencies in an environment.yml file:

```
name: lucid2_new
channels:
  - plotly
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - r
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - rpy2=2.9.4
  - _r-mutex=1.0.0
  - aniso8601=9.0.0
  - backcall=0.2.0
  - backports=1.0
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.1
  - blas=1.0
  - ca-certificates=2020.12.5
  - certifi=2020.12.5
  - click=7.1.2
  - cloudpickle=1.6.0
  - colorama=0.4.4
  - cycler=0.10.0
  - cytoolz=0.11.0
  - dask-core=2021.2.0
  - decorator=4.4.2
  - dill=0.3.2
  - flask=1.1.2
  - flask-cors=3.0.9
  - flask-restful=0.3.8
  - freetype=2.10.4
  - icu=67.1
  - imageio=2.9.0
  - intel-openmp=2020.2
  - ipython=7.20.0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0
  - jedi=0.18.0
  - jinja2=2.11.3
  - joblib=0.17.0
  - jpeg=9d
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1
  - lcms2=2.12
  - libclang=10.0.1
  - libpng=1.6.37
  - libtiff=4.2.0
  - llvmlite=0.35.0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3
  - markupsafe=1.1.1
  - matplotlib=3.3.4
  - matplotlib-base=3.3.4
  - mkl=2020.2
  - mkl-service=2.3.0
  - mkl_fft=1.2.1
  - mkl_random=1.1.1
  - networkx=2.5
  - numba=0.52.0
  - numpy=1.19.2
  - numpy-base=1.19.2
  - olefile=0.46
  - openssl=1.1.1j
  - pandas=1.1.3
  - parso=0.8.1
  - pickleshare=0.7.5
  - pillow=8.1.0
  - pip=21.0.1
  - plotly=4.14.3
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.16
  - pydoe2=1.3.0
  - pygments=2.8.0
  - pyparsing=2.4.7
  - pyqt=5.12.3
  - pyqt-impl=5.12.3
  - pyqt5-sip=4.19.18
  - pyqtchart=5.12
  - pyqtwebengine=5.12.1
  - python=3.7.9
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1
  - python_abi=3.7
  - pytz=2021.1
  - pywavelets=1.1.1
  - pyyaml=5.4.1
  - qt=5.12.9
  - r-assertthat=0.2.1
  - r-base=3.6.1
  - r-bh=1.69.0_1
  - r-bit=1.1_14
  - r-bit64=0.9_7
  - r-blob=1.1.1
  - r-cli=1.1.0
  - r-crayon=1.3.4
  - r-dbi=1.0.0
  - r-dbplyr=1.4.0
  - r-digest=0.6.18
  - r-dplyr=0.8.0.1
  - r-fansi=0.4.0
  - r-glue=1.3.1
  - r-magrittr=1.5
  - r-memoise=1.1.0
  - r-pillar=1.3.1
  - r-pkgconfig=2.0.2
  - r-plogr=0.2.0
  - r-prettyunits=1.0.2
  - r-purrr=0.3.2
  - r-r6=2.4.0
  - r-rcpp=1.0.1
  - r-rlang=0.3.4
  - r-rsqlite=2.1.1
  - r-tibble=2.1.1
  - r-tidyselect=0.2.5
  - r-utf8=1.1.4
  - retrying=1.3.3
  - scikit-image=0.16.2
  - scikit-learn=0.23.2
  - scipy=1.6.1
  - seaborn=0.11.0
  - setuptools=52.0.0
  - shap=0.37.0
  - six=1.15.0
  - slicer=0.0.7
  - sqlite=3.33.0
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0
  - tk=8.6.10
  - toolz=0.11.1
  - tornado=6.1
  - tqdm=4.57.0
  - traitlets=5.0.5
  - tzlocal=2.1
  - wcwidth=0.2.5
  - werkzeug=1.0.1
  - wheel=0.36.2
  - xz=5.2.5
  - yaml=0.2.5
  - zlib=1.2.11
  - zstd=1.4.8
```

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /app_dir 

COPY . . /app_dir

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml python==3.7.9

RUN echo "source activate lucid2_new" &gt; ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/lucid2_new/bin:$PATH


EXPOSE 9874

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

When trying to build the image however, several dependency conflicts get reported, even though I can perfectly install all dependencies and create the environment locally without using docker, I can't figure out what the exact problem is here. I get the following error report. There is actually a lot more output but due to size restrictions I can't share it here:

```
 UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
#9 2943.3
#9 2943.3 Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
#9 2943.3
#9 2943.3 Package _openmp_mutex conflicts for:
#9 2943.3 matplotlib-base=3.3.4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 libtiff=4.2.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-tidyselect=0.2.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-bit64=0.9_7 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 zlib=1.2.11 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pyqtwebengine=5.12.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-bit=1.1_14 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 mkl=2020.2 -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 r-rlang=0.3.4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 numpy=1.19.2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 r-tibble=2.1.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 xz=5.2.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 freetype=2.10.4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-rsqlite=2.1.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pyqt5-sip=4.19.18 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 cytoolz=0.11.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 rpy2=2.9.4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 zstd=1.4.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-utf8=1.1.4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 shap=0.37.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-purrr=0.3.2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pywavelets=1.1.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 mkl-service=2.3.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 sqlite=3.33.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 kiwisolver=1.3.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 libpng=1.6.37 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 blas=1.0 -> openblas -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 llvmlite=0.35.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 tornado=6.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 lz4-c=1.9.3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 scikit-image=0.16.2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pandas=1.1.3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 openssl=1.1.1j -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-fansi=0.4.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 tk=8.6.10 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 libclang=10.0.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 numpy-base=1.19.2 -> blas=[build=openblas] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 r-glue=1.3.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 scikit-learn=0.23.2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 qt=5.12.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 scipy=1.6.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 r-digest=0.6.18 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pillow=8.1.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 jpeg=9d -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pyqt-impl=5.12.3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 mkl_random=1.1.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 icu=67.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pyqtchart=5.12 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 numba=0.52.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pyqt=5.12.3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 lcms2=2.12 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-dplyr=0.8.0.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 markupsafe=1.1.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 mkl_fft=1.2.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5',build=*_llvm]
#9 2943.3 python=3.7.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 yaml=0.2.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 pyyaml=5.4.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-base=3.6.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
#9 2943.3 r-rcpp=1.0.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
```

Comment: jeeez just wandered what are all those dependencies for ? I mean do you really need all this ?

Comment: As error said you need to check your OpenMP version under the Docker with https://stackoverflow.com/a/13612520/5274713. Maybe `docker build --pull` will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem related to the copy instruction.

try with this dockerfile:

```sh
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /app_dir 

COPY . . # or COPY . /app_dir


RUN conda env create -f environment.yml python==3.7.9

RUN echo "source activate lucid2_new" &gt; ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/lucid2_new/bin:$PATH


EXPOSE 9874

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I think that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I'd try changing your channels to

```yaml
channels
  - plotly
  - conda-forge
  - defaults  # already includes anaconda and r
```

---

#### Minor notes

You don't additionally need `python==3.7.9` in the create command - it's already in the YAML.

Unless this is an ancient Miniconda image (pre-v4.4), one should prefer `conda activate`

```bash
RUN echo "conda activate lucid2_new" &gt; ~/.bashrc
# ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/lucid2_new/bin:$PATH # the previous command manages PATH
```